# How to change the image viewer in Python

Tags: python, image, scipy, imshow

Up to now, when I read and show an image in Python:

```
from scipy import misc
img = misc.imread("myimage.png")
misc.imshow(img)
```

it opens it by using ImageMagick.

How could I change the reader from ImageMagick to, say, Image Viewer?
I guess I should change the Python environment, but I do not have any further clue.

Comment: A quick internet search on misc.imread tells me misc is a "Miscellaneous routine" and I assume it must be using Imagemagick, although I can not find any reference to that in the documents. I would suggest you start there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docstring for `misc.imshow` says

```
In [10]: misc.imshow?
Signature: misc.imshow(arr)
Docstring:
Simple showing of an image through an external viewer.

Uses the image viewer specified by the environment variable
SCIPY_PIL_IMAGE_VIEWER, or if that is not defined then `see`,
to view a temporary file generated from array data.
```

Therefore, set the `SCIPY_PIL_IMAGE_VIEWER` environment variable to the path of your `eog` (Image Viewer) executable.

Comment: Where should I specify that variable?

Comment: That depends on your operating system. On linux, you would add `export SCIPY_PIL_IMAGE_VIEWER=/usr/bin/eog` to your `~/.profile`, then logout, then login again to make the change effective. For other OSes, perhaps try googling "set environment variable [your operating system]".

Comment: You can also do this within python: ```import os``` ```os.environ["SCIPY_PIL_IMAGE_VIEWER"] = "FOO"```

Comment: @unutbu brilliant!